# Setting default values in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

```
 :collection => FuelType.all.collect {|fuel| [fuel.fuel, fuel.fuel]}
```

How do I make the first value as default from this collection??

Comment: what isyour exact question??

Comment: I just want one value as default  from the collection.

Comment: If I am getting it right its option for select dropdown

Comment: Yes...its a dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
..., collection: -> { FuelType.pluck(:id, :fuel) }, input_html: { selected: FuelType.first }
```